# QwtPlot automatically resizes during AutoScale

Tags: c++, qwt

I'm using libqwt-6.1.1 to display variable data in a QwtPlot element (as histogram) using auto scale for y-axis. Depending on the actual data and the number of tics, the autoscale-run considers reasonable, the minimum height of the whole QwtPlot element often increases. This kills my whole layout design and frequently makes the window larger than the screen.

Now 2 questions:

1) How can I prevent the QwtPlot from being automatically enlarged?

2) How does the minimum size calculation actually work? (I got lost somewhere in QwtPlotLayout::activate() while trying to follow the calculation steps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the solution was simpler than expected ...

Overloading `QwtPlot::sizeHint()` and `QwtPlot::minimumSizeHint()` (which are virtual, fortunately) making both return an small constant value did the trick, i.e.

`QSize myPlot::sizeHint() const { return QSize(100, 100); }`

`QSize myPlot::minimumSizeHint() const { return QSize(100, 100); }`

Answer (score 0):

The factor that has an effect on the height and depends on auto scaling is the number of major ticks of the vertical scales ( tickcount * font height ).

The calculation of the ticks depends on the given stepSize. When the stepSize is set to 0 ( = default setting ) it is calculated from the maxMajor setting ( default: 8 ), what is an upper limit for the number of the major ticks.

So f.e. you could use a stepSize to 0 and set a reasonable maxMajor setting for your use case. Then use a QLayout setup, where the plot gets not always shrinked to its minimum height.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it didn't actually solve the problem but turned my research back into the right direction (see solution below).